# Tensorflow "DataLossError: Checksum does not match" when used with supervisor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been using tensorflow with `tf.train.Supervisor` -

```
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=path, save_model_secs=900)
with sv.managed_session() as sess:
    if not sv.should_stop(): 
        #Rest of the code
```

Recently, it crashed during training and since then it has been throwing the below error at the `with sv.managed_session()` line above -

> DataLossError (see above for traceback): Checksum does not match: stored 1057608875 vs. calculated on the restored bytes 763056116
>
> [[Node: save/RestoreV2_31 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_31/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_31/shape_and_slices)]]

Is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

This means your checkpoint file got corrupted. Delete the latest version (i.e. the one with the largest `global_step` number) and try again and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. There is only one checkpoint file though. Rest of the files in there are model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001, graph.pbtxt, model.ckpt.meta, model.ckpt.index and a few event.out.tfevents files.

Comment: I see. I didn't know that it could save backup checkpoints, it seems to save only one file in my case, is that some parameter in supervisor (other than save_model_secs) that allows it start saving more checkpoints?

Comment: That is the parameter. With MonitoredSession (replacement for Supervisor) you can use the CheckpointSaverHook to control the frequency.